# Adding Values From Combobox To Textfields

Tags: java, swing, combobox, textfield

I have a login form consisting of four fields as **servername, portnumber, username, password**

I have a combo-box besides that login form that should enable users to choose the last successful username (e-mail address) to be able to fetch values **(servername, portnumber, username, password)** into my text fields. I'm done with having that username in the combo-box.

I need to put values regarding that username into my four textfields once the user choose the username in the combo-box. I need help about being able to formulate that actionListener and Performed functions. I'm not exactly sure of the ones all the way down below. Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!!

```
//Two lines down below, those are my values that I want to assign to its respective text field

String user_name, server_name, port_number; // I have got the values
Char [] password; // I have got its value


JTextField serverText, portText, usernameText; // Those are my JTextField names to set values in it
JTextField passwordText;


    final JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.addItem(user_name); // Putting that username in the combo-box
    comboBox.setBounds(500, -13, 230, 70);
    panel.add(comboBox);

    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            procedure = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            private void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange()) == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    usernameText.setText(user_name);
               .......
                }

      }
        }
});
```

Comment: There are things about your code that don't make sense, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: There is no runnable example because I couldn't do so. I just want to learn how to do that action. The code that put there is kind of a template.

Comment: Well, you don't need the `itemStateChanged` listener witin the `ActionListener`.  If you want to learn how to do it, I suggest writing some code and trying something

Comment: I'm done with that. Thank you MadProgrammer for your continuous help. I shared it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way it works in case someone needs it in future. Since it is an action, and I don't want to mirror any changes within the combo-box itself, I've decided to have gone with ActionListener rather than ItemListener

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            {
                serverText.setText( (String) item.getServerName());
                portText.setText( (String) item.getPortNumber());
                usernameText.setText( (String) item.getUserName());
                passwordText.setText( (String) item.getPassword());
      }
    }
});
```